# SQL - select from the club name with an ordering so no two adjacent rows have the same club name

Tags: mysql

I've got the following result when I tried to fetch the results from the database with mysql command :

```
select player_id,full_name,club_name from players
```

something like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id |   full_name  |  club_name  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 3  | Maher Zein   |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 4  | Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 5  | Kamal saber  |   wadi dgla |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 6  | gamel kamel  |   el-nasr   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | saed ali     |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 8  | omar galal   |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 9  | Kamal saber  |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 10 | Kareem Gaber |   Enpy      |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 11 | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 12 | ehab zeyad   |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 13 | moaz maged   |   Smouha    |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 14 | mazen mahmod |   elmasry   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 15 | ahmed shawky |   Petroget  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 16 | shaker ali   |   Petroget  |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

but I have many adjacent rows have the same **club name**

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id |   full_name  |  club_name  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 3  | Maher Zein   |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 4  | Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

**OR**

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | saed ali     |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 8  | omar galal   |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 9  | Kamal saber  |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

**OR**

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| 11 | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 12 | ehab zeyad   |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

**OR**

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| 15 | ahmed shawky |   Petroget  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 16 | shaker ali   |   Petroget  |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

and I have tried to use `ORDER BY RAND(club_name)` but the result not accurate

The desired output would be something like that:

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id |   full_name  |  club_name  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 5  | Kamal saber  |   wadi dgla |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 6  | gamel kamel  |   el-nasr   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | saed ali     |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 11 | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 8  | omar galal   |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 3  | Maher Zein   |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 9  | Kamal saber  |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 4  | Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 11 | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 13 | moaz maged   |   Smouha    |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 14 | mazen mahmod |   elmasry   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 15 | ahmed shawky |   Petroget  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 10 | Kareem Gaber |   Enpy      |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 16 | shaker ali   |   Petroget  |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

can mysql do that or should I integrate php with mysql ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that no club has more than half the members, I think you can do this by enumerating the members with the clubs in order.  Then alternate from the first half and the second half using modulo arithmetic:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from players p cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by club_name
     ) p
order by rn % floor(@rn / 2), rn;
```

EDIT:

The above solution guarantees that clubs are not next to each other, but the clubs are not very random.  Here is another approach that is probably more what you want.

It is hard for me to explain *why* it works without a white board and some picture.  If you look at the details, it will probably be sort-of obvious.  We are going to enumerate each member of each club.  Then we are going to sort by a magic number, where the magic number is the sequential value times the number of members divided by the size of the club.  This will evenly distribute the clubs in the result set.

In SQL, this looks like:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = club_name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := club_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from players p cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := '') params
      order by club_name
     ) p join
     (select club_name, count(*) as cnt
      from players p
      group by club_name
     ) pc
     on p.club_name = pc.club_name
order by rn * (@rn / cnt);
```

Comment: Brilliant! very very good answer that exactly what i want thanks a billion !

Comment: hello i greatly appreciate your efforts .. can i combine this query with the query that filter some data something like `select full_name,club_name where club_name='El Ahly' AND club_name='Cocorico' AND club_name='smouha'  ` after that put your query to show the result as same as the result in your query in one query?