# SQL - print many word between every columns with many conditions

Tags: mysql

Ok first i have immutable values :

```
4   8   16   32   64   128   256
```

and i have one table something like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| id |   full_name  |  club_name  |  y_of_birth |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |    2000     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly   |    2000     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 3  | Maher Zein   |   El Ahly   |    2003     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 4  | Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly   |    2003     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 5  | Kamal saber  |   wadi dgla |    2000     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 6  | gamel kamel  |   el-nasr   |    2002     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 7  | omar galal   |   Cocorico  |    2000     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 8  | Kamal saber  |   Cocorico  |    2004     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 9  | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |    2000     |  
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 10 | ehab zeyad   |   Ismaily   |    2005     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 11 | moaz maged   |   Smouha    |    2001     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 12 | mazen mahmod |   elmasry   |    2006     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 13 | ahmed shawky |   Petroget  |    2002     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 14 | shaker ali   |   Petroget  |    2007     |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------+
```

and i have tried to filter data from database with query

`select full_name,club_name from players where y_of_birth=2000`

and the result is `5` players should be something like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name   |
+--------------+--------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly    |
+----+------+--+--------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly    |
+------+-------+--------------+
| Kamal saber  |  wadi dgla   |
+------+-------+--------------+
| omar galal   |   Cocorico   |
+------+-------+--------------+
| Mohamed gad  |  Ismaily     |
+------+-------+--------------+
```

Ok the condition is :

if the result is **more than** 4 `> 4` and **less than** 8 `<= 8` put the result in `8` in our case the result is `5` it mean `8 - 5 = 3`  mean iterate this word 3 times the result should be something like that :

```
+--------------+-------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name  |
+--------------+-------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |  El Ahly    |
+----+------+--+-------------+
| **ANY WORD** |             |
+--------------+-------------+
| Kareem Gaber |  El Ahly    |
+------+-------+-------------+
| Kamal saber  |  wadi dgla  |
+------+-------+-------------+
| **ANY WORD** |             |
+--------------+-------------+ 
| omar galal   |  Cocorico   |
+------+-------+-------------+
| Mohamed gad  |  Ismaily    |
+------+-------+-------------+
| **ANY WORD** |             |
+--------------+-------------+
```

**Note:** please no adjacent between `**ANY WORD**` to above example :

```
+------+-------+
| **ANY WORD** |
+--------------+
| **ANY WORD** |
+--------------+
```

**OR**

no adjacent between `club_name` to above example :

```
+------+-------+
|    El Ahly   |
+--------------+
|    El Ahly   |
+--------------+
```

***Updated :***

another examples again

it based on those numbers

```
4 8 16 32 64 128 256
```

and the **condition is:**

1. if **query result** <= `4` and > `2` it mean `(4 - the number of query result)`

**example :** if the query result is `3` so `4 - 3 = 1` so `1` is a number of `**ANY WORD**` so the desired output will be like that :

```
+--------------+-------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name  |
+--------------+-------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |  El Ahly    |
+----+------+--+-------------+
| **ANY WORD** |             |
+--------------+-------------+
| Kareem Gaber |  El Ahly    |
+------+-------+-------------+
| Kamal saber  |  wadi dgla  |
+--------------+-------------+
```

2. another **example** with `8`
   if **query result** <= `8` and > `4` it mean `(8 - the number of query result)`

for example :
the **query result** is `5` so `8 - 5 = 3` so `3` is a number of `**ANY WORD**` so the desired output will be like that

```
+--------------+-------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name  |
+--------------+-------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |  El Ahly    |
+----+------+--+-------------+
| **ANY WORD** |             |
+--------------+-------------+
| Kareem Gaber |  El Ahly    |
+------+-------+-------------+
| Kamal saber  |  wadi dgla  |
+------+-------+-------------+
| **ANY WORD** |             |
+--------------+-------------+ 
| omar galal   |  Cocorico   |
+------+-------+-------------+
| Mohamed gad  |  Ismaily    |
+------+-------+-------------+
| **ANY WORD** |             |
+--------------+-------------+
```

and so on with `4` and `16` and `32` and `64` ..etc till `256` .

Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: are you manually querying the database? Or using any programming language ?

Comment: @mustangDC yes with php but i want to fetch all results from database with the same result as same as in the question !

Comment: i guess... you should get a `count` of the `select` results and programmatically iterate the `select` query `count` number of times.

Comment: @mustangDC yes i did but the problem is **ANY WORD** printed in the last part of my code and i have many many divs it make me very nervous so i hope someone here give me a simple way to do this in mysql  my application about tournament brackets .

Comment: try to run `select ... from ....` instead off any thing else. it will provide you the results with the column headers

Comment: wow this really starts to be too complicated without php.. I can't come up with any simple solution for your problem (nor complicated).

Comment: @CosLu i did with php but the result of **ANY WORD** located in the last result not between every column  bro because i have many many `divs` i can't  integrate it with my php code .

Comment: But if you can use php why don't you just get "players where y_of_birth=2000" and then you build the table that you desire with it? Do you have any limitation?

Comment: yes i have many many `divs`

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do.  Are you saying the following: Let's call the  number of results, N. If N is a multiple of 2 then display those many rows with nothing in between.  Otherwise display 2 ^(floor(log N) + 1) rows. Let's call that number X.  Then fill in every other row until you have filled in X-N rows.

Comment: @danb check updated with more examples .

Comment: the examples are fine, but it is not clear what is the problem (so the question too). as I can understand, you want to have a number of 2^N records in the result set, but where do you exactly want to add the extra records (`any word`)? It does not seem to be impossible with a query, but you must have a good reason to do sg like this ;)

Comment: @autprivate:  Check whether my formulation is correct.  You can also use 2^ceil(log(N)) for X.

Comment: @danb so why ceil ? ..  i think it can be done with mod .. so it will be something like `8%5=3` which `8` is a one of those immutable values and `5` is a number of result records and  `3` is a number of `**ANY WORD**`  but it should be with if condition .

Comment: Looks like all the numbers above are powers of 2.  For the case you mention where n =5, log(5) = 2.321928094887362 (Base 2 log).  So ceil(log(N)) is 3.  Now 2 to the power of that is 8.   You need a total of 8 records.  Subtract that from N and you get 3.   Try my formula. I believe it works in all cases.  Then you can use that to solve your problem

Comment: Is there any order you want to the results that are returned?

Comment: You will run into an important problem here. Let's say 5 people are born in 2000, and all are part of the club El Ahly. If you can only use three separators, you will be forced to have repeating club names.

Comment: @McAdam331 yes you are right but rarely happens

Comment: @authprivate okay, I will try to enhance my answer. Currently, it protects against repeating separators.

Comment: @authprivate I have edited my answer. During testing I found another edge case. Consider year 2003 in your sample data. You have two results, which means the next power of 2 is 2, and 2-2 is 0, so you won't have a separator. Is that okay?

Comment: @McAdam331 Ok no. of `ANY WORD` is right but i have tried that code with large result of query and i found many adjacent between many `club_names` and please i don't want many iterations between two club_names for example `El Ahly vs Ismaily` and the same `El Ahly vs Ismaily` and again `El Ahly vs Ismaily` and another two club_names iterate again `Cocorico vs wadi dgla` and again `Cocorico vs wadi dgla` and so on ...

Comment: @authprivate I thought I understood, but I guess I don't. I have no idea what you mean by "I don't want many iterations between two club names." There is nothing consistent here. The only consistent requirement is the number of separators you are looking for, and not to repeat club names. Now you're telling me you need to avoid too many rows in between club names, how do you determine the number of rows that should be in between them?

Comment: @McAdam331 what i mean if i have large result of query for example `214` player so i the number of `ANY WORD` is `42` all `ANY WORD` should be distributed to all `214` players but with conditions no adjacent between two `club_name` to above for example `El Ahly` above `El Ahly` too or `Ismaily` above `Ismaily` too another condition no adjacent between `ANY WORD` to above too another condition `"I don't want many iterations between two club names"`  here's meant i don't want two same `club_name` iterates with each others every times one or two maximum times .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New and improved (version 3 how) using variables and using basically the same trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31214773/3113342):

```
SELECT
  IF(is_real, '**ANY WORD**', full_name) AS full_name,
  IF(is_real, '', club_name) AS club_name
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      full_name,
      club_name,
      (@row_num2:= @row_num2 + 1) AS row_num
    FROM
      (
        SELECT p3.*
        FROM
          (
        SELECT
          p2.*,
          (@row_num := @row_num + 1) AS row_num
        FROM
          (
            SELECT *
            FROM players AS p1
            WHERE y_of_birth = 2000
          ) AS p2
        CROSS JOIN
          (
            SELECT
              @row_num := 0,
              @count := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players WHERE y_of_birth = 2000)
          ) AS vars
        ORDER BY club_name
      ) AS p3
    ORDER BY row_num % FLOOR(@row_num / 2), row_num
  ) AS p4
CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      @row_num2 := -1,
      @extra := GREATEST(2, POW(2, CEIL(LOG2(@count)))) - @count) AS vars
  ) AS data
LEFT JOIN
  (
    (SELECT 1 AS is_real)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT 0 AS is_real)
  ) AS filler
ON
  MOD(row_num, FLOOR(@count / @extra)) = 0 AND
  row_num / FLOOR(@count / @extra) < @extra
ORDER BY row_num, is_real
```

For the example data you gave, this produces something like:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| full_name    | club_name |
+--------------+-----------+
| Ahmed Sayed  | El Ahly   |
| **ANY WORD** |           |
| Mohamed gad  | Ismaily   |
| **ANY WORD** |           |
| omar galal   | Cocorico  |
| **ANY WORD** |           |
| Kareem Gaber | El Ahly   |
| Kamal saber  | wadi dgla |
+--------------+-----------+
```

This should work for any size result; just change the condition (`y_of_birth = 2000`) to be whatever condition you want.  I upgraded to MySQL 5.6 to test this (it actually turned out to make a small difference).

The basic trick is to create a two-row table with static values (in this case, `1` and `0`) using a `UNION` and then `LEFT JOIN` that into the actual results some number of times to fill up to a power of 2.  This means we have calculate the number of each row in the result (called `row_num`) so that we can formulate the join condition properly.  In the end, this produces a duplicate row every so many rows; the final bit is to change what we select on those duplicates (using `IF`s) by checking if we are on a real or fake (`1` or `0`) row.

This should prevent players from the same team being next to each other unless this is impossible because one team has too many players; see the link above for more about how to do that.  The basic idea is to order by club and then alternate picking from the first half and the second half of that list.

The final trick was to figure out how many and where to join in the dummy rows.  After trying several things, I realized that this is actually very easy: just join with every row until we have reached the desired number of dummy rows (`@extra`).  However, that will pack all the dummy rows at the top of the results; to spread them out more (not perfectly spread out, but more spread out), calculate how often we need to add one (`FLOOR(@count / @extra)`) and then put one every that many rows (the first part of the `ON` condition) until enough have been added (the second part).

Comment: i greatly appreciate your input, thank you. but i tried your query but it gave me many adjacent `**ANY WORD**` check this please http://oi61.tinypic.com/2niuyph.jpg

Comment: @authprivate What version of MySQL are you using?  I'm guessing there's an issue where the default ordering for something is different between your version and my version.

Comment: its a phpmyadmin and the version of mysql is `5.6.21`  .

Comment: @Austin look at this post plz and the answer is right no adjacent between one to next or above `club_name` latest query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214722/sql-select-from-the-club-name-with-an-ordering-so-no-two-adjacent-rows-have-th/31214773#31214773

Comment: @authprivate Ok, I made some changes; see if it works now.  If not, could you update your question with the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE players`?

Comment: @Austin man you are doing a great job and now no adjacent between `club_name` with output `**ANY WORD**` .. but this is found mistakes  with the number of `**ANY WORD**` specifically when im trying to filter number of  for example 128 or 256 look at the result here it gave me empty http://oi62.tinypic.com/353bn8h.jpg and please don't start with `**ANY WORD**`

Comment: @Austin bro sorry but the number of `**ANY WORD**` not accurate ,,, you are in progress to solve my problem please keep it up .

Comment: @authprivate Ok, I think I finally have it this time; try it now.

Comment: @Austin bro you did it the number of `**ANY WORD**` right but please could you change the location of `**ANY WORD**` for example after two `fulle_name` or every three names ...etc Thanks a lot  for your co-operation!

Comment: @authprivate I improved the spread of `**ANY WORD**`s; it's not perfect, but it should be good enough.

Comment: @Austin that's very good man brilliant .. but i just have one problem there are many iterations between two many club_names for example `El Ahly` vs `Ismaily` and the same  `El Ahly` vs `Ismaily`  and again `El Ahly` vs `Ismaily` and another two club_names iterate again `Cocorico` vs `wadi dgla` and again `Cocorico` vs `wadi dgla` and so on .. with all club_names this is not good it will causes alot of problems .. is there anyway to solve this problem to be one or two maximum times Thanks again for your co-operation!

Comment: @authprivate Sorry, I think I would have to resort to stored procedures and temp tables to get that done.  The issue is that the mechanism that prevents duplicates conflicts with any kind of randomization or even distribution of teams in a fundamental way; I would have to come up with a totally new approach.  If temp tables and procedures are OK with you, then I could try it that way.

Comment: @Austin Ok Austin if no between `**ANY WORD**`,no club_name adjacent  ,no iterations between the same two clubs  its ok you can go a head .. but sorry for this dumb question i can totally combine these with my php code isn't it ha ? i'm really appreciate your efforts and thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

The following procedure will return 4 columns. The first and second columns should be displayed. The third column is just the rownum which should be ignored. If the fourth column is not blank then display it in the next row otherwise don't display it.

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure test()
BEGIN
declare N int;
declare X int;
select count(*) from players where y_of_birth=2000 into N;
set X = power(2,ceil(log2(N))) -N;
SELECT full_name, club_name, @row := @row + 1 AS row, 
case when (@row<= X) 
then 'any word' else '' end r
FROM players, (SELECT @row:=0) z
where y_of_birth=2000;
END //
DELIMITER 

call test;
```

Comment: appreciate your efforts and thanks for reply but bro i don't know where is the problem this is found problem with syntax error  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5c1e/1

Comment: @authprivate It works in mysql, not sure about sqlfiddle

Comment: @authprivate  Meant to say it works after my correction in mysql

Comment: im really sorry for being late to answer but the problem is im using phpmyadmin and im trying and searching about how to call `procedure test ` on phpmyadmin and i did on sqlfiddle and the same error .

Comment: @authprivate  For sql fiddle, define the procedure in the left side where you build the schema. Leave out the "DELIMITER //" in the first line and the "DELIMITER" in the last line.   Then underneath where you have [Build Schema]  [Edit Fullscreen]  [Browser] and  [ ; ] buttons, choose the last button and pick // for the query terminator.  Make sure you use the updated procedure where I removed the comma

Comment: check the result again bro the same syntax error http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f041e/4

Comment: @authprivate  As mentioned in previous comment. Remove the Delimiter // from the first line and the DELIMITER of the last line. Also the procedure should be in the left side not the right side as you have it.  When I do that it works in sql fiddle.

Comment: thanks for your code ... but the number of `**ANY WORD**` wrong it should be `3` not `2` if the number of result names <= `8` and > `4` in this example the number of result is `5` so the number of `**ANY WORD**` should be `8-5=3` .. i want to combine `**ANY WORD**` with column `full_name` without any adjacent between same `club_name` or adjacent `**ANY WORD**` and the location of `**ANY WORD**` not located between every name every 2 or three or more  .

Comment: @authprivate  Fixed it again

Comment: @authprivate  By the way, although it may be possible, it seems to me that sql alone is not well suited for returning alternative rows.  Instead this should be accomplished in the programming language on the front end. In other words, from the results in the query given here, you could easily construct the rows for display on the front end, using the front end programming language. What are you using on the front end?

Comment: yes i know and i did but i have limitations because i have many many `divs` and although if i did it with php the `**ANY WORD**` located in the last columns not between columns .

Comment: @authprivate  You should show your php code. This should not be that difficult

Comment: thanks bro greatly appreciate your efforts upvote +1 .