# SQL - can i add word every column?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add temporary word every column with loop or anything else on mysql ? when im try to `select full_name from players`.

Can I do something like that for example :

```
+--------------+
|  full_name   |
+--------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |
+----+------+--+
| **ANY WORD** |
+--------------+
| Kareem Gaber |
+------+-------+
| **ANY WORD** |
+------+-------+
| omar galal   |
+--------------+
| **ANY WORD** |
+------+-------+
| Mohamed gad  |  
+------+-------+
| **ANY WORD** |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Do it in your application,its pretty easy in any language

Comment: i know and i will but i need this result specifically from database !

Comment: Can do you use procedures?, if so...

Comment: @eyp it can be done with procedures ?

Comment: Well, in a procedure you can have a loop, so you can go through your results and add something for each row... Create a temp table and insert a value from your original query, another for the row.

Comment: @eyp so any example plz ?

Comment: i can do it on the fly without any changes ? mean temporary ?

Comment: ...Unsure if this will help... `select 'word ' + col from table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining a table with itself.
I've made an example for you: (you can use this test table if you want to try my code and reuse it in your tables).

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO test
    (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
    (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java')
;
```

And the query:

```
    SELECT
     CASE
     WHEN query = '1' THEN productName
     ELSE "ANY WORD"
     END AS name
     FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS query, t1.* FROM test AS  t1
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS query, t2.* FROM test AS t2
)AS t3 ORDER BY id, query;
```

Ask whatever you need if it's not clear.

Not sure how to save a query in sql fiddle but you can paste it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f530/1

Comment: hello could you please check this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259849/sql-print-many-word-between-every-columns-with-many-conditions