# php / SQL - print many word 4 times between every 4 names with many conditions

Tags: php, mysql

i have asked this question before here in this topic please read it carefully [sql-print-many-word-between-every-columns-with-many-conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259849/sql-print-many-word-between-every-columns-with-many-conditions/31317762)

but the difference between this question and previous one that i want to make a collective players or group of players inside many club names for example :

`El Ahly` club name have a `12` players i want to split it into `3` `teams` every `team` has `4` players what i want to count how many `team` inside every club names
then put them inside immutable numbers (groups) `4   8   16   32   64   128   256` based on the number of `teams` print `**ANY WORD**` between them something like that after filter data with `select full_name,club_name from players where y_of_birth=2000` the desired output should be like that :

***UPDATED :***

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Maher Zein   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ahmed shawky |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shaker ali   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar Saed    |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| moataz Gamal |   Petroget       |
+------+-------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hassan maged |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| zakareya gad |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamel kamel  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar galal   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| khaled zein  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady sameer |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| wahed mahmoud|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| samy shahen  |   Petroget       |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| Mohamed gad  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ehab zeyad   |   El Ahly        |
+----+---------+------------------+
| moaz maged   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen mahmod |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
```

in this example there are `2 groups of` `**ANY WORD**` because its a `6` `group` and put them inside `8` immutable group which found in `4` or `8` or `16` or `32` or `64` or `128` or `256` numbers ... and no adjacent between 2 `**ANY WORD**` or two adjacent between `club_name`

**Examples :**

*4 players as a one player*

if the result after `select full_name,club_name from players where y_of_birth=2000` is `12` players it mean `12 players` = `3 groups` because every group have `4` players next step print `**ANY WORD**` 4 times (note: `**ANY WORD**` is a one of these groups) between 3 groups so the output will be like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Maher Zein   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ahmed shawky |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shaker ali   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar Saed    |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| moataz Gamal |   Petroget       |
+------+-------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamel kamel  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar galal   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
```

**Conclusion :**

`4 8 16 32 64 128 256` are immutable groups

`group 4` should fill of `16` players with `**ANY WORD**` with no adjacent between them something like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Maher Zein   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ahmed shawky |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shaker ali   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar Saed    |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| moataz Gamal |   Petroget       |
+------+-------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamel kamel  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar galal   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
```

`group 8` should fill of `32` players with `**ANY WORD**` with no adjacent between them something like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Maher Zein   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ahmed shawky |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shaker ali   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar Saed    |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| moataz Gamal |   Petroget       |
+------+-------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hassan maged |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| zakareya gad |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamel kamel  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar galal   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kamal saber  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| **ANY WORD** |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
| khaled zein  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady sameer |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| wahed mahmoud|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| samy shahen  |   Petroget       |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| Mohamed gad  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ehab zeyad   |   El Ahly        |
+----+---------+------------------+
| moaz maged   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen mahmod |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
```

and so on with

`group 16`
`group 32`
`group 64`
`group 128`
`group 256`

***EDITED:***

i have got this query from *Gordon Linoff*

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = club_name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := club_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from players p cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by club_name
     ) p
order by floor((seqnum - 1) / 4), club_name
```

after combined with data filtered :

```
select p.*
from (select p.full_name,club_name,
             (@rn := if(@c = club_name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := club_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from players p  cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params  WHERE `y_of_birth` LIKE N'%2000%'

      order by club_name
     ) p 

order by floor((seqnum - 1) / 4), club_name
```

output something like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Maher Zein   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| kamal mado   |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hossam magdy |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| sayed ammar  |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| karem gad    |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohamed gad  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ehab zeyad   |   El Ahly        |
+----+---------+------------------+
| moaz maged   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen mahmod |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| shaker ali   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar Saed    |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| moataz Gamal |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamael zayed |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen kamal  |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mesho kareem |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mano mazen   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady srour  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mamdouh gamal|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| khaled zein  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hassan maged |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| zakareya gad |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady sameer |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| wahed mahmoud|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| samy shahen  |   Petroget       |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| abdo samy    |   Petroget       |
+----+------+--+------------------+
```

any help would be appreciated !

Comment: This is a display problem. Why not do this application-side rather than on the database?

Comment: @tadman becasue i have many limitations .

Comment: You haven't explained those, so I'm going to re-iterate: Why not do this in your application? Trying to do this in the database is at least ten times harder than simply manipulating a result array. You'll probably need to use a stored procedure for the pure database approach.

Comment: @tadman the problem is i have many many `divs` and the application is a tournament brackets with a customized rules and i did that with php but when im trying to add `**ANY WORD**` it gave me the result located in the last places for example all names then all `**ANY WORD**` because the array from database not the same with the array of my php code i can't combine them into one to randomize my `**ANY WORD**` with my `full_names` with no adjacency between them .

Comment: The database should only be concerned with storing and retrieving data, possibly ordering, but not cleaning things up or organizing things into grouped lists. That's a display problem, and the best place to tackle that is in PHP if that's where you're using this data. Results are easily fetched into arrays, and arrays are **easily** manipulated like this. Expressing this kind of convoluted business logic in a query is going to make for a seriously ugly, probably unmaintainable query. Doing it in PHP means it's easy to test, and easier to understand the code.

Comment: @tadman ok any suggestion, example with php would be appreciated i will edit my tag to be with mysql with php .

Comment: Since it can be done in php now, could you should what a result array from a query would look like. An array before the solution and after the solution? The **ANY WORD** thing is confusing me a little, so I feel it would give me a little more context. Also what if the result were 13 players, would that be split into groups of 4 still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your previous post and this one. If I get the idea, the basic thing is you have teams and you have players and you want to display data in certain standardized groupings (so-to-speak).

Well, there is a constant datum that you are always comparing to which is the size of the team.

What I would do is make a subquery that groups the team with a count of the players and use this in some fashion as follows:

```
select t.*
       , x.total_players
       -- , row_number() over(order by t.team_name) row_id
from team_table t
    join (
          select team_id
                , count(1) total_playerss
          from team_table 
          group by team_id
         ) x on x.team_id = t.team_id
order by t.team_name
```

When echo'ing out the result set in PHP, you can build some function such as:

```
<?php

function add_some_word($playerCount) {

if ($playerCount >4 && $playerCount <= 8) {
echo '*** SOME WORD***';
echo '*** SOME WORD***';
echo '*** SOME WORD***';
}
else if ($playerCount >4 && $playerCount <= 8) {
echo '*** SOME WORD***';
echo '*** SOME WORD***';
}
// etc.
}

?>
```

Using the `row_id` from the result set, you can see when a team starts and ends.

So when it is spitting out the rows it could be something like:"

```
<?php

$currentTeamName = "";

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null,PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
// echo data you would normally send out

if ($currentTeamName != $row['team_name']) {
add_some_word($row['total_players']);
}

}

?>
```

I hope I got your question right. I am dashing this off fast but I thought it would help!

Comment: thanks for your reply .. but i have tried your query but look at the result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8938/4  i'm really don't know where is the problem .

Comment: Looks like your version of mysql doesn't support the row_number() function so I removed that from the query and I modified the "While" loop so hopefully it does what you want it to do. If you get the concept, I think you can modify it so it does what you want it to do.

Comment: AFAIK, no MySQL version support row_number()