# SQL - select from the club name with an ordering so no 4 adjacent rows have the same club name

Tags: mysql

I've got the following result when I tried to fetch the results from the database with mysql command :

select full_name,club_name from players where y_of_birth=2000

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Maher Zein   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| Mohamed gad  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ehab zeyad   |   El Ahly        |
+----+---------+------------------+
| moaz maged   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen mahmod |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| ahmed shawky |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shaker ali   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar Saed    |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| moataz Gamal |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamael zayed |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mano mazen   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady srour  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mamdouh gamal|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| khaled zein  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady sameer |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| wahed mahmoud|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| samy shahen  |   Petroget       |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hassan maged |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| zakareya gad |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen kamal  |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mesho kareem |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| kamal mado   |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hossam magdy |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| sayed ammar  |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| karem gad    |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
```

but i want the desired output like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|   full_name  |  club_name       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Maher Zein   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| kamal mado   |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hossam magdy |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| sayed ammar  |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| karem gad    |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| Mohamed gad  |   El Ahly        |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| ehab zeyad   |   El Ahly        |
+----+---------+------------------+
| moaz maged   |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen mahmod |   El Ahly        |
+--------------+------------------+
| shaker ali   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| omar Saed    |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| moataz Gamal |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamael zayed |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mazen kamal  |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mesho kareem |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mano mazen   |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady srour  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| mamdouh gamal|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| khaled zein  |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| husein mazen |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| hassan maged |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| maged ahmoud |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| zakareya gad |   Cocorico       |
+--------------+------------------+
| shady sameer |   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| wahed mahmoud|   Petroget       |
+--------------+------------------+
| samy shahen  |   Petroget       |
+----+------+--+------------------+
| abdo samy    |   Petroget       |
+----+------+--+------------------+
 and so on if more 
 .......
```

any help would be appreciated !

Comment: you should at least make it clear what the order you want is, with *words*. took me a minute to understand about the lowercases

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Care to explain your question more? I usually get it from the input/output but this is pretty confusing.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the input.

Comment: sorry for all i know i have mistakes im really in rush.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry its a typo my bad sorry and your answer is very good but where can i combine my query that filter data with y_of_birth=2000 for example  i added my question with this query i'm sorry just forgot to add it to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the clubs have a similar number of players, you can enumerate the rows and basically order by the enumeration:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = club_name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := club_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from players p cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by club_name
     ) p
order by floor((seqnum - 1) / 4), club_name
```

Comment: thanks for your answer could you please this bounties question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573922/sql-print-many-word-4-times-between-every-4-names-with-many-conditions you answer the half of it just  put `**ANY WORD**` with a conditions that i typed